# How to make lines thinner in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, adobe-photoshop-elements

I have a png image which is having thicker lines and i need to make this lines look thinner. I really dont know how to do this..
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? The reality is you'll need to redraw things to alter line weights if the image is a PNG.

Answer (score 1):

I have made it work...
first i have selected the image with magic wand tool, then added stroke inside it with black color..
Then saved it and reopened the new png file..
Then with background eraser tool,i have removed the black color so it got thinner..

Comment: That's got about 3 more steps than is strictly necessary. If OP is insistent on doing this in PS, just using Select Colour to select the blue, then contract the selections, inverse the selection, and hit delete.

Comment: @AMontpetit Maybe a few extra steps but if the result is similar in quality and took 10 seconds longer, I think it's alright! OP found his own answer and decided to post it, that's a good idea. You could explain to the OP what were the extra steps you think are not necessary though so OP can learn something new from this. And post your comment as a complete answer with screenshot of the final results wouldn't be a bad idea for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to select all the pixels. Because they're all one color you can select all the blue pixels: `Select` > `Color Range`.

(Other ways are `Select` > `All`, or `ctrl` + `lClick` on the layer's thumbnail. More complex images may need different selection methods like the Magic Wand tool, Quick Select tool, chroma key, or using channels to make a selection.)

Invert the selection so everything *except* the blue pixels are selected: `Select` > `Invert`

Make the selection smaller: `Select` > `Border`. Try different values here. Look at the moving, dotted lines around the selection area to visualize how much will be left after the next step.

Press the `delete` key to erase the selected area from your layer